# Does a learning AI make sense as an opponent in a game?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I want to build an AI opponent for a simple game of four in a row. However, I don't simply want to create a perfect player, which would be rather boring for the human. Instead, I would like to have an AI that practically starts from zero and learns the game over time.

The only approach to this that I know of are artificial neuronal networks. However, it seems that these usually require supervised learning. Also, [this document](http://users.auth.gr/kehagiat/GameTheory/12CombBiblio/TicTacToe.pdf), for example, states that the AI only approaches being a perfect player after about 20k games - a bit too much for a human to play.

Therefore I wonder: Is it possible to make reasonable use of a learning AI in a simple game? Are there any suitable alternatives or extensions to neuronal networks to do this job?

Comment: This might be a better question over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: To overcome the 20k games limit an option might be to let the program play against itself and thus learn a better strategy.

Comment: Playing a game with scores or with wins and losses *is* supervised learning.
Also, I think it would be smarter to provide a partly trained network with the game, not a completely blank one.

Comment: @Junuxx: From my understanding it is reinforced learning, since the moves cannot be judged until the game is completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any algorithm or technique off the top of my head that will let a computer learn a game on anything comparable to the same time scale as a human being.  But we have to be careful when we talk about time scale.

There is, for instance, a technique developed by Fogel and Chellapilla, which plays a bunch of randomly generated neural networks against each other, and then uses a genetic algorithm to create new and better neural networks based on the results.  This was originally done with checkers, but would be applicable to many games.  That technique at least removes the burden of human training-- the networks are playing against themselves.

But how fast does that learn?  Fogel and Chellapilla got good quality results (Class A performance, which is just under rated Expert) on checkers in only about 250 generations... but each generation's tournament included about 150 separate games, for about 37k games total.  If you played a game a day, it would take you 100 years to play that many.  Maybe people who play at that level have played ten games a day for ten years, but that seems... unlikely.  So in that sense, slower than a human being.  On the other hand, a good laptop can probably play that many games in a week, which no human could ever do.

So if you're looking for a training routine where a human being will be able to train and perceive the performance increase on a reasonable scale... I know of nothing that can do that, today.  (Which stands to reason-- our best supercomputers still don't have the raw processing power of a human brain, and we have no algorithms designed to take advantage of that much power, yet.)

If you're just looking for an imperfect AI, though, you might try a technique like Fogel's and Chellapilla's, and instead of taking the ultimate, near-expert rated results, just take something from halfway through the run, or something from the last generation but not the best result.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to looking into the field called "General Game Playing". The focus there is on learning to play games that the computer has never seen before. The algorithm is handed the rules of the game in a well-defined format and it has to learn to play from scratch.

The state of the art techniques pretty much always incorporate some sort of Monte-Carlo simulation where the system plays thousands of games against itself in simulation as it simultaneously plays the "real" games against humans or other programs that it's being measured on.